# How can I import code from LaunchPad.net?

Tags: svn, launchpad

I want to import code from Launchpad.net.
How can I do it?

Is that using SVN? Can I use SVN to keep updated with the code changes?

Thank you so much,
Robert

FYI: this is the code I want to import 
https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-commiter/openobject-addons/trunk-extra-addons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's bazaar only. The command it gives is: `bzr branch lp:openobject-addons/extra-trunk`

More info here: [Using Bazaar with Launchpad](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.1/en/tutorials/using_bazaar_with_launchpad.html)